# Merge tags [Polymer-1.0] and [Polymer-1.x]

Tags: feature-request, tags

There are two different tags but with absolutely the same meaning. [polymer-1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/polymer-1.0) and [polymer-1.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/polymer-1.x). I don't know about any significant changes between subversions of version 1 at all. Plus [polymer-1.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/polymer-1.x) is very uncommon even if it's much more accurate.

When you are asking question and you type `Polymer` in tag search field, it finds only [polymer-1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/polymer-1.0) and not [polymer-1.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/polymer-1.x). When I was asking first time, I was using Polymer 1.7 and I was very confused when I couldn't find Polymer-1.x.

Also, there is new version of Polymer (2.0) which is absolutely different. But there is no tag [polymer-2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/polymer-2.0), only [polymer-2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/polymer-2.x), so it would be great to have the same reasoning for [polymer-1.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/polymer-1.x).

Comment: Guess you want merge and add a synonym maybe ?

Comment: i think merge [tag:polymer-1.0] into [tag:polymer-1.x] would be enough.